# how to parse returned value from asmx

Tags: php, web-services, asmx

I want to send some values from php to an asmx webservce.
my code work's fine, but the return value is like this :

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["any"]=> string(963) "123" }
```

now, how to get  `123` value ?

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new SoapClient("http://****/service.asmx?WSDL");
$params->UserName   = '1';
$params->PassWord   = '1!';
$params->Ip         = '1!';
$params->MacMain    = '1!';
$params->PcName     = '1!';
$result = $client->GetPassPort($params)->GetPassPortResult;
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: try this : `$result->any`

Comment: plz post your comment as an answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while getting data from object you need to use `->` operator.Just use below code to get `123` as :

`$result->any`

Comment: The "any" attribute doesn't seem to be a normal string. The square brackets are not the same as in an regular object dump. This would look like `object(stdClass)[1] public 'any' => string '123' (length=3)`